# How do I add a line to a specific stanza in a config file?

Tags: bash, configuration, shell-scripting

My configuration file, `server.conf`, has the following format:

```
[general]
setting1=sdfdsf
setting2=asdfadsf

[ssl]
setting1=sadfsdf
setting2=sdfadsfkljasdf
```

How do I add an additional setting to the `[general]` stanza using a Bash script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^\[general\]/\[general\]\nnew=setting/' file
```

which adds `new=setting` after the `[general]`. 
using `sed -i.bak ... file` will do it in place and create a `file.bak` for safety.

Comment: usually you want to add new settings to the end of a section, can you add an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be mostly answered over on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284518/how-to-insert-a-line-using-sed-before-a-pattern-and-after-a-line-number

Basically its a job for SED or AWK and a little regex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as given below

```
cat server.conf
[general]
setting1=sdfdsf
setting2=asdfadsf

[ssl]
setting1=sadfsdf
setting2=sdfadsfkljasdf
```

```
sed  '/general/,/^$/s/^$/setting3=new_entry\n/g' server.conf
```

```
cat server.conf
[general]
setting1=sdfdsf
setting2=asdfadsf
setting3=new_entry

[ssl]
setting1=sadfsdf
setting2=sdfadsfkljasdf
```